# How to use Layout View and View Properties in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

I've seen some windows (Layout View, View Properties, Tree View, Tree Overview) between Android windows in Eclipse but I cannot use them because they are always empty.
How can they be used? I hope they could be useful in drawing or showing layouts.

Comment: I too would like to know... anyone?

Comment: I also want to know.... any one?

Answer (score 4):

With ADT 9.0.0 all those views disappeared in Eclipse and apparently moved back to the hierarchyviewer.

However with ADT 8.0.0 and ADT 8.0.1 you have those view options.

Tree View

The Tree View depicts your layout as a tree hierarchy. It just shows your layouts view hierarchy. If you click on one of the view elements you get its View Properties.

View Properties

By clicking on one of the view elements in the Tree View you can view the elements view properties in this view. Things like layout options.

Tree Overview

The Tree Overview just allows you to navigate through your tree hierarchy more easily if the hierarchy happens to be quite big.

Layout View

Using the Layout View you can inspect your layout element by element. It just shows all your layout elements relative to each other. You can view them like a wireframe.

To use all those views you first have to connect a device to the computer or start an emulator and start an activity whose layout you want to inspect. Open the Windows view in Eclipse, select the activity you want to fetch the layout from and hit the Load the view hierarchy into the tree view. From now on you can use all the different views as described above.

Keep in mind that all of those views are no longer in Eclipse but again in the standalone hierarchyviewer in your sdk/tools directory.